# Retrieve XML from https using WebClient/HttpWebRequest - WP7

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to retrieve an XML document from a server and store it locally as a string. In desktop .Net I didn't need to, I just did:

```
        string xmlFilePath = "https://myip/";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
```

However on WP7 this returns:

```
Cannot open 'serveraddress'. The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.
```

So I set about using the WebClient/HttpWebRequest example from [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-WebClient-and-HttpWebRequest.aspx), but now it returns:

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

Is it because the XML is a https path? Or because my path doesn't end in .XML? How do I find out? Thanks for any help.

Here's the code:

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string baseUri = "https://myip:myport/service";
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted +=
            new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(
            client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        client.DownloadStringAsync
          (new Uri(baseUri));
    }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
            resultBlock.Text = "Using WebClient: " + e.Result;

        else
            resultBlock.Text = e.Error.Message;
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request =
          (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseUri));
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback),
        request);
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request =
          (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response =
          (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        using (StreamReader streamReader1 =
          new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();
            resultBlock.Text = "Using HttpWebRequest: " + resultString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you just cut and paste the URL from your code to a browser?

Comment: An XML page, formatted correctly by Firefox. Like this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I rather think you've overcomplicated things. Below is a very simple example which requests an XML document from a URI over HTTPS.

It downloads the XML asynchronously as a string and then uses `XDocument.Parse()` to load it.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://domain/path/file.xml"));
    }

    private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

            this.textBox1.Text = xdoc.FirstNode.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I've ended up with, however the exception still occurs. Does this code work for you? If so I'm pretty sure it must be down to my HTTPS cert being non-trusted.

Comment: @JoeBeez yep, hate to say it but "works on my machine".  It may be  a cert issue.  Your example code includes specifying a port as well. If you are specifying https as the protocol and a non standard port this may be the problem. (I've known HTTPS have issues using ports other than the default on other platforms.)

Comment: Yea the port was going to be my second thing to check when I get home cheers for all your help.

Comment: But the problem is that if  we use the WebClient, it runs in the UI thread. Its better to go for the HttpWebRequest.

Comment: @Mahantesh - since Mango, WebClient returns on the thread it was called from. It doesn't force the response on to the UI thread unless it started there. The above was an example of simplest form, not best practice.