# WP7 error: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, delicious-api

I have this code that it used to work, but at some specific time it stopped to work and returned the error "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

```
        WebClient deliciousWebClient = new WebClient();
        deliciousWebClient.Credentials = Credentials;
        deliciousWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://api.del.icio.us/v1/tags/get"));
        deliciousWebClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Error == null)
            {
                …
```

Any suggestion on this error?

In this code, the error is pointing to delicious endpoit, but the same error is happening with some other services...

Comment: is it possible the internet capability was accidently removed from your Manifest file? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/2a24a9b0-6cf9-480a-930d-866b82a33caf

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840438/httpwebrequest-returning-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-notfound-on-wind

Comment: this can happen when some kind of proxy authentication is required for accessing that url.

Answer (score 1):

The `NotFound` error is a classic 404 error, so it's possible that the API endpoint is down or that it changed on you.

I'd start by using [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com) to make the requests manually. That'll help you figure out whether the issue is in your code somewhere or on the API side.

It's hard to get Fiddler working with the WP7 emulator, as you noted below. One trick I've used in the past when I got really desperate was to write a quick console app that used the same code that my Windows Phone app was executing. Then I was able to successfully intercept the traffic. It turned out that my request being properly formatted.

Comment: Thanks, but in my Win8 App the call is sucessfull, and since the WP7 App is running in the WP7 emulator, fiddler2 is not able to cach the calls..

Comment: Nop, in Win8 there's no WebClient… In WinRT there is a "new" class in charge of the http calls: HttpClientHandler. But this cannot be used in WP7...