# How do I load an xml file in XDocument in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

XDocument has no load method contrary to XMLDocument so how do I load an XML content from the Internet with an url ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `XDocument` does have a `Load(Uri)` method, but it's only for navigating to pages within your app. It's a static method, so you do `XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("/somepage.xaml");`. The documentation for the `Load(string)` method is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx).

If you want to access an external URL, you need to use the `WebClient` class. Here's an example that I just tested in a Windows Phone 7 app (which is basically SL3):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XDocumentTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.xml"));
        }

        private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)    
        {        
            if (e.Error == null)        
            {            
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);            
                TextBlock1.Text = xdoc.FirstNode.ToString();        
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457894/retrieve-xml-from-https-using-webclient-httpwebrequest-wp7) is similar, but involves `https`, which I don't think you're dealing with.

Comment: hello I tried but it doesn't call handler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423591/why-httpscompleted-is-not-called