# Windows Phone Post Client

Tags: parsing, windows-phone-7, post, authentication, webrequest

How can I use this (http://postclient.codeplex.com/) dll library to my Windows Phone project, if I want log in (not only log in) to website via URL.

Example: Adress for login is: http://xchat.centrum.cz/~guest~/login/index.php?name=nickname&pass=password

After that, I want parse HTML, if I have hash from url - but it's a long story. :)

Thanks for help. :)

EDIT:

I found something like:

```
 private void Button1Clk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
            string strName = "nickname";
            string strPass = "password";

            UTF8Encoding encoding=new UTF8Encoding();
            string postData="name="+strName;
            postData += ("&pass="+strPass);
            byte[]  data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

            // Prepare web request...
            HttpWebRequest myRequest =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xchat.centrum.cz");
            myRequest.Method = "POST";
            myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            Stream newStream = myRequest.GetResponse();
            // Send the data.
            newStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
            newStream.Close();
    }
```

But script has error with GetResponse();

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you dont need the POST-Client for that, because your Example-Login works with GET. Just use a HttpWebRequest to load the Site and you can readily parse your HTML.

Here is a perfectly fine example (in the Answer): [Retrieve XML from https using WebClient/HttpWebRequest - WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457894/retrieve-xml-from-https-using-webclient-httpwebrequest-wp7)

Just take the Url (http://xchat.centrum.cz/~guest~/login/index.php?name=nickname&pass=password) to parse the HTML-Response you want.

Comment: Some example script would be help. :( Because I have some code of string the page, but I don't know, what do next.