# MediaPlayerLauncher with HTTPS

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to open an audio file from an HTTPS resource.

First, I tried using `MediaPlayerLauncher` like so:

```c#
MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher {
    Media = filename,
    Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause,
    Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Portrait,
    Location = MediaLocationType.None
};
mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```

`filename` in this case is a URL beginning with `https://`.

Using Fiddler to monitor traffic, I have noticed that `https://` in `filename` is getting changed to `http://`.

Next I tried opening the same URL using `WebBrowserTask`:

```c#
WebBrowserTask webBrowser = new WebBrowserTask {
    Uri = filename
};
webBrowser.Show();
```

Checking Fiddler out again, I noticed that two requests are being sent. First is a request to `filename` by the browser. This results in the "Tap to open file" message to appear in the browser. Tapping it opens the phone's media player (`MediaPlayerLauncher`?), which sends another request -- in this case, the `https://` changed to `http://` again (which is similar result to first attempt).

The server I am getting the file from only supports HTTPS, hence the problems arising when the media player requests the file as HTTP.

Is there anyway to stream a file from an HTTPS resource? Does Windows Phone's media player even support it?

Answer (score 0):

Pointing location on the internet for the MediaLuncher is a bad idea. It will freez UI thread and your app won't be responsive. Try first download the audio as a stream and then play it. Use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to open a stream. [HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457894/retrieve-xml-from-https-using-webclient-httpwebrequest-wp7) can be open in WP7, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the app deactivate anyway when you use `MediaPlayerLauncher`?