# XDocument load xml file issue

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am trying to load the **Xml** file by using XDocument.Load() method. When this function invoke visual studio fire an error

> Cannot open 'file:///C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/{A1256902-95B7-495C-BB35-65AAE6B2D48D}/Local/XMLFile1.xml'. The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.

**MyCode**

```
 IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        string folderfilename = folder.Path + "\\" + "XMLFile1.xml";

        doc = XDocument.Load(folderfilename);
```

Can anybody please tell me why I am getting this error ?

Comment: here have an example of how to solve it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457894/retrieve-xml-from-https-using-webclient-httpwebrequest-wp7

Comment: @LiranElisha Thank you for reply. My file is in local folder. It gives me an error "An exception occurred during a WebClient request".

Comment: i'm sorry but i have nothing more to offer... have you tried using relative path? as in string `folderfilename = "\\" + "XMLFile1.xml"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try reading the isolated filestream instead of refering to the physical file path?

```
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("xmlfile1.xml", FileMode.Open, myIsolatedStorage))
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
    }
```